# Model energy usage as sinusoidal with period 1 year; for what $n$ can we split year into $n$ equal-length parts with equally sized bills?

Tags: calculus

Say I am in the northern hemisphere and my domestic energy consumption peaks in February and bottoms out in August. Model this as a sinusoidal curve with period 1 year, such that

$$C = \int_{y_1}^{y_2} {(x+k\,\mathrm{cos} (2\pi y))}dy$$

where
$y:=$ time measured in fraction of a year from say 15 February,
$x:=$ mean rate of consumption, measured in energy units per year;
$k:=$ a constant expressing amount of variation;
$C:=$ consumption between $y_1$ and $y_2$, measured in energy units.

Assume the cost per unit of energy is constant throughout the year.

If I want to pay equally-sized bills twice a year, with each bill being for an equally long period, i.e. half a year, then clearly I should ensure that the boundaries between billing periods fall on 15 February and 15 August. (Assume months are of constant length.)

But let's say I want to pay equally-sized bills $n$ times a year, with each bill being for the period of $\frac{1}{n}$ of a year. We have stated the answer for $n=2$. The case $n=1$ is trivial: you can start the billing period whenever you like. But for what other values of $n$ do solutions exist? And when must the billing periods start and end for these various possible values if they exist?

(Note: this question comes out of my own wondering and is not any kind of homework.)

Comment: I'm wondering whether the answer might be that there are no other possible values of $n$. I think maybe if $n\geqslant3$ then the bill for the period that contains the peak must be greater than the mean bill for the other $n-1$ periods and therefore $\unicode{10803}$.

Comment: If you have $n$ bills with equal size and equal period, then you can calculate the mean value of them all which is of course the size of a single of such bills. But that mean value must by definition be equal to the yearly mean value. Looking at the cosine shape you must then conclude that that is only possible for $n=2$ where each billing period runs from min to max (or the other way around) of the cosine. To be a bit more illustrative: the cosine itself is zero-mean, so each billing period must have a bit of the cosine below AND above the year average $x$.

Comment: You could have two unequal length periods though.

Comment: @JeroenBoschma - "_(T)he cosine itself is zero-mean, so each billing period must have a bit of the cosine below AND above the year average x._" This is a nice observation. When $n=3$, the period that includes the peak can have a small part (no more than $\frac{1}{12}$ of a year, i.e. a month) for which the rate is less than $x$, but its mean will always be greater than $x$. Now I am wondering, given  $n=3$ or $n=4$, how we can tidy up some equal-billing periods given that we can't make them of equal length. But that's another question!

Comment: Given the fact that the cosine crosses the average $x$ only at 2 places, and combined with the previous observation, $n$ is always restricted to 2. Take one of those crossings and an arbitrary period symmetrical around it, then the billing equals the average. The same holds for the remaining period around the other crossing.  But that's really as far as it goes I think.